# How to support multi-language with php for href links?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, href, multilingual

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html) to add another language using PHP to my website. The problem I ran into is the href links don't work properly.

I have a header.php file

```
<header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="banner">
        <div class="container">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="index.php"><?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="startup.php"><?php echo $lang['MENU_STARTUP']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="projects.php"><?php echo $lang['MENU_PROJECTS']; ?></a></li> 
                    <li><a href="about-us.php"><?php echo $lang['MENU_ABOUT']; ?></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.php"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>                        
                </ul>

        </div><!--/.container-->
    </nav><!--/nav-->
</header><!--/header-->
```

that I load into my index.php, about-us.php, contact-us.php, etc... for each page using

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

The problem is I need the href to link to index.php?lang=en to view my english home page and index.php?lang=fr to view my french home page. Since both page share the same header file, both pages link to index.php instead of index.php?lang=en or index.php?lang=fr when I select my home tab. How do I fix this?

Another related issue, I have a footer.php file that included in all my pages

```
<footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue navbar-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12"><a href="index.php?lang=en""><u>EN</u></a> | <a href="index.php?lang=fr""><u>FR</u></a> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer><!--/#footer-->
```

and when I'm on different page(about.php), I want to translate the page that I'm on and not index.php. How do I do this?

Comment: Use conditionals before the include. Rough version `switch($_GET['lang']) { case 'fr' : include('includes/french.php'); break; default : include('includes/english.php');}`

Comment: You should normally only translate the strings, not have separate pages for each language.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Each of my pages translate all the strings for each language. The problem I'm having are href links that I need to append ?lang=en or ?lang=fr depending on the selected language.

Comment: For the footer links, assuming the query string triggers the translation, do `<a href="?lang=en">`. That will load the current page with the query string appended. Just like an anchor. Append that same string to your navigation links, populated from a variable.